# Variable not showing value in template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following segment of code in view:

```
image = [
    'register.png',
    'checkin.png',
    'checkin.png'
]
imagetext = [
    'Register Patient',
    'Checkin Patient',
    'Checkin Patient'
]
link = [
    '/clinic/%s/register' % cliniclabel,
    '/clinic/%s/checkin' % cliniclabel,
    '/clinic/%s/checkin' % cliniclabel
]
zipsidebarstuff = zip(image, imagetext, link)
return render(request, 'clinic/cliniccurrent3.html', 
              {'rnd_num': randomnumber(), 'clinic': clinicobj,
               'checked_list': checkedin_list, 'patientcount': patientcount,
               'type':'live', 'ClinicUserName': name, 'showhelp': helpneeded,
               'NumUnconfirmedAppts': NumUnconfirmedAppts(clinicobj),
               'zipsidebarstuff': zipsidebarstuff})
```

In my template I have:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="sidebar-nav-fixed pull-right affix">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="d-inline-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
          {% for image, imagetext, link in zipsidebarstuff %}
          <div class="p-2 bd-white">
            <div class="d-inline-flex flex-column">
              <div class="p-2 flex-fill bd-highlight">
                <a href="{{ link }}"><img class="imgsidebtn" 
                   src="{% static 'clinic/img/{{ image }}' %}" /></a>
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 flex-fill bd-highlight">
                <a href="{{ link }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ imagetext }}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
      {% include "clinic/helpbar.html" with location="livelist" foo=bar %}
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is in showing the tag

```
<a href="{{ link }}"><img class="imgsidebtn" 
                          src="{% static 'clinic/img/{{ image }}' %}" /></a>
```

in the rendered html. It is shown as:

```
<a href="/clinic/jeslineye/checkin"><img class="imgsidebtn"
 src="/appointments/static/clinic/img/%7B%7B%20image%20%7D%7D"></a>
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a variable inside a `{% static %}` tag. What you can do is to use [`get-static-prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#get-static-prefix) and construct the URL manually. For example:

```
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}clinic/img/{{ image }}">
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use template variable inside `static` tag like this:

```
{% static 'clinic/img/{{ image }}' %}
```

Instead use [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with) and [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter

```
{% with "clinic/img/"|add:image as image_url %}{% static image_url %}{% endwith %}
```